# Display events stored in MongoDB in SyncFusion Calendar via GraphQL

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion-calendar

I am working on an app and I'd like to display the events that are stored in MongoDB using my GraphQL end points. This is how I do it:

```
  List appointments = Query(
      options: QueryOptions(document: gql(_getEvents)),
      builder: (result, {fetchMore, refetch}) {
        if (result.isLoading) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          result.data!["events"];
        }
        throw const Text('Something happened');
      }) as List;
  return _DataSource(appointments);
}
```

However, I get an error saying that 'The type 'Query is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast'. Apparently flutter doesn't like that I cast Query as List. The question is 'Is there a way to make the cast work'? Or is there any other applicable workaround?

Thank you in advance